# A 3×n rectangle table contains pieces of three colors (n pieces for each color).

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Condition**: A $3 \times n$ rectangle table contains pieces of three colors (n pieces for each color).

**Requirement**: Prove that you can rearrange the pieces in each row so that each column contains pieces of all colors.

I've tried proving by induction and got the obvious base case $(n = 1)$. But I still have no idea to carry out the induction step.

Every correct way of proving will be accepted. I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.

Comment: In case n = 1, we have only one column (3 cells), and as we also have the number of pieces of each color equals to n (n = 1). So on the column, we will get 3 pieces having different colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should rearrange the rows such that the first column has pieces of all three columns.

This is easy when every color appears in all three rows.  Suppose there is a row with only two colors; say, row 1 has red and blue cells, but no green. Then you can pick a green cell from row 2 or row 3, then make an arbitrary decision for row 3 or row 2, then you'll always have an option left for row 1. This strategy also covers the case where row 1 only has one color in it.

Finally, when you've taken care of the first column, induct to take care of the other $n-1$.

---

For the general case of a $k \times n$ rectangle with $n$ pieces of each of $k$ colors, the approach is the same, except picking out the first column is harder. Take a bipartite multigraph with the $k$ colors on one side, the $k$ rows on the other. For a piece of the $i^{\text{th}}$ color in the $j^{\text{th}}$ row, draw an edge from the $i^{\text{th}}$ vertex on one side to the $j^{\text{th}}$ vertex on the other side.

As a multigraph, this is $n$-regular, so it has a perfect matching by a standard application of Hall's theorem, and that tells us how to pick the first column.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much!